# How to show title tag of span irrespective of highlighting

Tags: jquery, html

I have a title tag for a span and want that to be in work even if the user hightlights the span or not.

`<span title="Show me always">No need to highlight me</span>`

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/r52japzz/)

Is there a proper way to do that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Its unclear what you're asking.

Comment: If you want to display it always... why not move it to the content part

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/owx802ft/2/

Comment: i have an icon of warning for a login form while registering, and that icon would highlight only when there is an invalid text has been entered, and adding up the title for the actual content doesnt look good, is there any other way to do?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/owx802ft/3/

Comment: You can put it in another `span` and show it when you want it

Comment: `span` tag doesn't work like title, so i don't think its better to use in that way